# Tomee jpa settings

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jta, apache-tomee

Cant deploy app with exception  java.lang.Exception: persistence-unit: persistence -750441533localhost: Name "openejb/PersistenceUnit/persistence -750441533localhost" not found. 
Was tried a many configs. Any suggestions for settings?

persistence .xml

```
  <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="persistence">
    <description>Hibernate JPA</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/postgres</non-jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
   <properties>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

context.xml

```
   <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/postgres">
      <Resource name="jdbc/postgres"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                username="root"
                password="root"
                driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base"
                maxTotal="20"
                maxActive="25"
                maxIdle="3"/>
    </Context>
```

Errors

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
14-Jun-2019 17:21:36.774 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication 
undeployException original cause
 java.lang.Exception: deployment not found: .Comp1964794492

14-Jun-2019 17:21:36.777 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] 
org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication 
undeployException original cause
 java.lang.Exception: persistence-unit: persistence 
-750441533localhost: Name "openejb/PersistenceUnit/persistence 
-750441533localhost" not found.

org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Jta config for tomee:

main/resourses/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>persistence</description>
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

tomee\conf\tomee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
  <!-- see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html -->

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
  <!-- <Deployments dir="apps" /> -->
  <Resource id="MyDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
JdbcDriver          org.postgresql.Driver
JdbcUrl             jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
UserName            un
Password            pass
JtaManaged          true
DefaultAutoCommit   true
</Resource>
</tomee>
```

Eclipselink maven:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa
```

Don't remember to put jdbc drive .jar into tomee\lib.

Also note, eclipselink working only with tomee plume.

Comment: I have the same problem and did exactly as you but still having the error. How do you write your @Persistence annotation in your classes ? If I do ``@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistence")`` I still have the same error.

Comment: Yes, you need to add @PersistenceContext to your classes. I think the best solution is use wildfly with hibernate.) I didnt have any problems with config wildfly.